# Window title text is truncated in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer

I have a situation where the document title is truncated in the tabs of Internet Explorer. I cannot reproduce it on my own machine, but according to the reports, it occurs when the user is directly typing the URL before navigation.
(EDIT: It can also occur when user right-clicks a link and opens it in a new tab...)

Clicking a link on the page (even one to the same page) seems to restore the title text again.

It seems to occur mostly on windows 10, but I have no reliable statistics to back this up, as it only seems to be a visual error, and we have no way of measuring how often it occurs.

I am also having trouble with my google fu in finding anything that even seems to be related to this problem.

Hence, I have not provided any sample code. I do have two screenshots of the toolbar with and without the error visible, but I am not sure it would add much to this question. I will of course be happy to provide any other information to help solve this of course, but as I am a bit stumped I don't really know what to include...

Comment: Note: Adding adding a re-assignment of document.title (just document.title = document.title in a document ready handler) seems to alleviate the symptoms. But that doesn't seem to be the right solution... or is it?

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to duplicate the error with debugging tools open.
I am still stumped - the document.title really is only two characters long when the error occurs.

So the "fix" in my comment above really did nothing, and it was probably just a fluke or placebo that I thought it did anything.

I ended up solving this by passing the correct title in another element, and the reassigning the document.title with that value.

The error is thus not solved, but I have a working workaround..
(Therefore I will not mark this question as answered)